# How can I use a TypeScript enums values as type?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, enumeration

How can I use a typescript enum values as a type for `templateTypeId` in `ISupportedTemplateType`. The values are 1, 2, 3, and I want that to be the type of `templateTypeId`

```js
export enum ETemplateType {
  'Cover Letter' = 1,
  'Wire Instructions' = 2,
  'Amendment' = 3,
}

export interface ISupportedTemplateType {
  templateTypeId: number; // HOW CAN I USE ENUM HERE?
  templateTypeName: keyof typeof ETemplateType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just... use it:

```
export interface ISupportedTemplateType {
  templateTypeId: ETemplateType;
  templateTypeName: keyof typeof ETemplateType;
}
```

Then this works fine:

```
// works
const obj: ISupportedTemplateType = {
    templateTypeId: ETemplateType['Cover Letter'],
    templateTypeName: 'Cover Letter'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKIBVirAGwEMZgsBPMYOAbwCg44ByAYQgDdgo4AZYGEqIzgBeOAEYANPSYB1AJZQqASUQBnGFGQBjGHIhqhogExSGjAIKokAEyuIYhuAGYpAX1q1QkWHDn3OAGaEWsoAyshg3iTWOHhEJOSUNNIkccSkFMBK1gBcmLEE6YnAANwpuIUJmQByhFZ5ANbAZBABcDCZrfkV8RmUZe60APRDcADu0A2qtFr66nAQAEYAVnlK4ZHQ0QW9xSLJDAyplX1Zud1pVZQA2izsnDx8AowAuqaHx7s1dcB5dxxcXj8TiMWiuIA)